# Diplay remote Harddrive with WMI and PHP

Tags: php, wmi

need some help with my `dashboard`. I played arround with **WMI** for Windows to get some data from my host. I used this to connect to my host:

```
$pc = "192.168.xxx.xxx"; //IP of the PC to manage

$WbemLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
$WbemServices = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer($pc, 'root\\cimv2', 'username', 'password');
$WbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;

$wmi_disks            =    $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");
$wmi_computersystem   =    $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
$wmi_operatingsystem  =    $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
$wmi_networkadapter   =    $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPENabled = 'True'");
```

i can display the ip adress and some other things.

My Problem is that i can not display the free space from my hosts hard drive.
How can i get this code to work with my host:

```
$fso = new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
$D = $fso->Drives;
$type = array("unbekannt","herausnehmbar","Festplatte","Netzwerk","CD-ROM","RAM Disk");
foreach($D as $d ){
   $dO = $fso->GetDrive($d);
   $s = "";
   if($dO->DriveType == 3){
       $n = $dO->Sharename;
   }else if($dO->IsReady){
       $n = $dO->VolumeName;
       $s = file_size($dO->FreeSpace) . " frei von: " . file_size($dO->TotalSize);
   }else{
       $n = "[Geräte mit Wechselmedien]";
   }
```

echo "Drive " . $dO->DriveLetter . ": - " . $type[$dO->DriveType] . " - " . $n . " - " . $s . "
";

```
}

  function file_size($size)
  {
  $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
  return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes';
  }
```

i used PHP.

Comment: What error message do you see? What output do you expect from this program?

Comment: The code display's how much drive space is left on the local machine.
I need that on a remote pc.